# More efficient ways to get around a recursive loop using a batch file to compare folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy

To give some context, the application I work on has a web path and an application path. The web path will always contain the standard file, but the file in the application path may be modified. I am looking to copy the file from the application path into a custom folder, based on the modified date. I have tried using fc/comp but have not had any luck. The script below works, however, it is inherently slow due to the nested recursive loop. It does the following:

-Check the modified date of source and target file

-If they are different, it will copy to a custom folder

-It will write to a log after each entry

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? Unfortunately, it needs to be a bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF

::The CustomFolder is the directory that will be created in the ReportPath

set webpath=<<UNC_PATH_HERE>>
set reportpath=<<UNC_PATH_HERE>>
set customfolder=\Custom_Folder
::Will check if custom folder exists and create it if it does not. 
::From there it will always add on to the file instead of replacing

IF NOT EXIST %reportpath%%customfolder% (MKDIR %reportpath%%customfolder%)

IF NOT EXIST %reportpath%%customfolder%\_transferlog.txt (type NUL > %reportpath%%customfolder%\_transferlog.txt)

echo ^%date% %time%^ --- Backup of modified files began. If you do not see a completed message then it was terminated early. >> %reportpath%%customfolder%\_transferlog.txt

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::Looping through files in webpath and comparing to reportpath
::If file exists in web path and report path but has different modified date 
::then the version from the reportpath will be copied into the CustomFolder and an entry will be made on the log

FOR /R %webpath% %%G IN (*.*) DO (
set sourcefile=%%G
set targetfile=!sourcefile:%webpath%=%reportpath%!
set sourcefilename=%%~nxG
set sourcetime=%%~tG
    FOR /R %reportpath% %%H IN (!sourcefilename!) DO (
    set targettime=%%~tH
    IF NOT "!targettime!"=="!sourcetime!" IF NOT "!targettime!"=="" echo f | xcopy "!sourcefile!" "!reportpath!!customfolder!\!sourcefilename!" /S | echo Filename: !sourcefilename! ----- Source Modified: !sourcetime! ----- Target Modified: !targettime! ----- Copied: %date% %time% >> %reportpath%%customfolder%\_transferlog.txt
IF "%1"=="loop" goto :eof
)
)

::Outputting completion message and closing cmd

echo ^%date% %time%^ --- Completed transfer of modified files >> %reportpath%%customfolder%\_transferlog.txt
exit
```

Comment: What do you think is happening with `echo f | xcopy ...`? Does the file get copied. Check the parameters of the `xcopy` command. `XCOPY /?` It is not the same as a `COPY` command. What would you say makes this recursive?

Comment: My apologies if I am not using the correct terminology. I was referring to the nested for /R loops. I don't require all of the directories within the paths to be processed, only all of the files within the given path. I have tried many different variations with no luck. It takes roughly 2 hours to process ~4000 files, so I'm not sure if this would be the most efficient option.

Comment: A lot of time could be saved by not having the inner loop traverse the disk. Before the first loop starts, create a temp file containing the timestamp and filename under %reportpath%. Scanning this file for the !sourcefilename! would probably be faster than searching the disk directory structure.

Comment: For each file found anywhere within the `%webpath%` directory structure, a nested check within the `%reportpath%` structure is being undertaken. I suppose that's what they mean by recursive. What isn't needed is delayed expansion, or a single variable being set within your for loop.